# ATmega (Arduino) programming in 3V system

Tags: arduino, atmega, isp

I want to use a ATmega (168 or 328) with a 3V button cell. Which isn't the problem but at the moment I think about how to make it pogrammable in the target board. The board will have some peripheral devices like leds which can't operatet at a higher voltage.

So can a normal ISP programmer or even a USB to TTL adapter be used to programm this 3V system?

Answer (score 1):

You can find [USB to TTL adaptors](http://www.adafruit.com/products/70) that are 3.3v compliant
(Use your power source not the one provided by the adaptor)

and some [ISP programmers](http://www.oddwires.com/usb-isp-3-3v-5v-avr-programmer/) will have a jumper to choose the voltage